# How do you read a specific line in a text file in Lua

Tags: io, lua

I have the need in Lua to read a specific line in a text file I select, I know how to open it:

```
filename = "hallo.txt"
fp = io.open( filename, "r" )
```

but I don't know how to read a specific line in that specific text file.

How do you though?

Answer (score 2):

If you have to do it several times, then read the whole file into memory, storing the lines in a table.

If you only have to do this once, try something like this:

```
local n=0
for l in io.lines(filename) do
   n=n+1
   if n==lineno then process(l); break end
end
```

Comment: So I need to type in my file l and it stops at l?

Comment: It increments lines until line numer is equal to `lineno`, which you must set somewhere earlier. Then it invokes a hypothetical function `process` and passes the line as a string argument. Once `process` returns, it breaks out of the loop.

Comment: Can you make you comment more simple?

Comment: You declare `lineno` before the loop. `lineno` is the line number you want to retrieve. You then change `process(l)` to whatever you want to do with the line. `l` contains text of your line.