# How to read specific line using io.read()

Tags: file, io, lua

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
io.open("__Equivalent-Exchange__/config/EMCfixed.lua", "r")
var1 = io.read(,*n)
```

Now I want to be able to set the row of the file that is specified with `io.open`. What is found was this:

[The reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.8) state:

> When called with a file name, it opens the named file (in text mode), and sets its handle as the default input file. When called with a file handle, it simply sets this file handle as the default input file. When called without parameters, it returns the current default input file.

That didn't help me so I found the `io.lines` piece.:

> Opens the given file name in read mode and returns an iterator function that works like `file:lines(···)` over the opened file. When the iterator function detects the end of file, it returns no values (to finish the loop) and automatically closes the file.
>
> The call `io.lines()` (with no file name) is equivalent to `io.input():lines("*l")` that is, it iterates over the lines of the default input file. In this case it does not close the file when the loop ends."

BUT, How can I specify what line to read?

P.S. for other info on the topic I found [this page](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/lua/lua_file_io.htm), I didn't understand it. But it might help your in the process of helping me.

Comment: `io.read('*n')` is equivalent to `io.input():read('*n')`.  `io.input()` simply returns current input file handle, which equals to `io.stdin` by default.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I actually don"t know what you mean, Could you try to rephrase it to fit the edits done by @YUHao?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you read a specific line in a text file in Lua](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21604238/how-do-you-read-a-specific-line-in-a-text-file-in-lua)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot jump directly to a specified line, because that would require you to *know* where that line is. Without reading the whole file up to at least this point, this is only possible if the lines have a fixed length (in which case you could use [file:seek](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-file:seek)). However, if you do not have fixed-length lines, you'll have to iterate over the lines, counting as you go:

```
function getNthLine(fileName, n)
    local f = io.open(fileName, "r")
    local count = 1

    for line in f:lines() do
        if count == n then
            f:close()
            return line
        end
        count = count + 1
    end

    f:close()
    error("Not enough lines in file!")
end
```

**Edit**: Note that you should not use this function if you are searching for multiple lines of the same file (e.g. you need lines 3, 5 and 8). In this case, the function above would open the file three times - that's a waste of system resources. Instead, you could define a function to be called on every number and check for matching line numbers there:

```
function checkLine(lineNumber, lineContent)
    -- Disregard odd line numbers
    if lineNumber % 2 == 0 then
        -- do something with lineContent
    end
end

local f = io.open(fileName, "r")
local count = 1

for line in f:lines() do
    checkLine(count, line)
end

f:close()
```

Comment: thanks, although I have made the program make the file thus know exactly on which line what information is. would then it be possible?

Comment: As I said, it's only possible if you know the exact position (in bytes). If you happen to only ever write lines with exactly the same amount of bytes, you can calculate the position and pass it to file:seek(). If the lines have different lengths, you're quite possibly out of luck. If you can give us two or three example files, we might be able to tell you if calculating the position is possible.

Comment: I indeed do not have the total spot in bytes. thanks for the help. this solved it